# Redirecting from one page to another without the parent page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, parse-platform

I'm having trouble in starting the windows phone application from a different page instead of MainPage.xaml but dynamically. Here's the code:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (appSettings["Parse.CurrentUser"] != null)
    {
        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Welcome Back","Welcome",MessageBoxButton.OK);
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/email.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        //Above step causes error as a Null Exception. :(
    }
    else
    {
        // show the signup or login screen
    }
}
```

So, if the user is already looged in I don't want to show the MainPage and instead i want to show email.xaml page. Kindly help with the `NullException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NavigationService` is not available yet in page constructor. Try to move your code from page's constructor to page's `OnNavigatedTo()` event :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (appSettings["Parse.CurrentUser"] != null)
    {
        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Welcome Back","Welcome",MessageBoxButton.OK);
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/email.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
    else
    {
        // show the signup or login screen
    }
}
```

Comment: what am i supposed to do in the constructor? I mean how do i call an event in a constructor?

Comment: nothing. `OnNavigatedTo` is invoked by system automatically when your application successfully navigated to the page. It is at later stage compared to constructor call

Comment: thanks a lot buddy. It worked like a candy. And i almost forgot this was very handy while redirecting to a particular panorama element. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Add this function to the app.xaml.cs. And call it within App constructor

```
    void SetupUriMapper()
    {
        // Get the UriMapper from the app.xaml resources, and assign it to the root frame
        UriMapper mapper = Resources["mapper"] as UriMapper;
        RootFrame.UriMapper = mapper;

        // Our dummy check -- does the current time have an odd or even number of seconds?


        // Update the mapper as appropriate
        if (!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("id"))
            mapper.UriMappings[0].MappedUri = new Uri("/LoginPage.xaml?method=UriMapper", UriKind.Relative);
        else
            mapper.UriMappings[0].MappedUri = new Uri("/MainPage1.xaml?method=UriMapper", UriKind.Relative);
    }
```

Update your App.xaml like this

```
    <Application 
x:Class="YourApp.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"       
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:UriMapper="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Navigation;assembly=Microsoft.Phone">
<!--xmlns:unsupported="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Unsupported">-->
<!--Application Resources-->
<Application.Resources>

    <UriMapper:UriMapper x:Name="mapper">
        <UriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/MainPage.xaml" />
    </UriMapper:UriMapper>

</Application.Resources>

<Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
    <!--Required object that handles lifetime events for the application-->
    <shell:PhoneApplicationService 
        Launching="Application_Launching" Closing="Application_Closing" 
        Activated="Application_Activated" Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"/>
</Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
```

Comment: You need to save some user id after login in the isolated storage to check user is logged in or not.

Comment: @Praveen_-_Systematix how can I add a method to a constructor you mean adding the contents right?

Comment: You need to call this function within constructor like this.SetupUriMapper(); You can define the complete function anywhere in app.xaml.cs page.

Comment: Error is shown here:  `UriMapper mapper = Resources["mapper"] as UriMapper;
            RootFrame.UriMapper = mapper;`  mapper is throwing null exception.

Comment: Also my Resources[] doesn't contain any key like mapper.. :/

Comment: you need to add this in app.xaml  <Application.Resources>

        <UriMapper:UriMapper x:Name="mapper">
            <UriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/MainPage.xaml" />
        </UriMapper:UriMapper> </Application.Resources>

Comment: Add this refernce also in the app.xaml xmlns:UriMapper="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Navigation;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"

Comment: Now this: Error 1 The name "UriMapper" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:System.Windows.Navigation;assembly=Microsoft.Phon‌​e". c:\users\abhishek de\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Mammmail_WP8\Mammmail_WP8\App.xaml 12 9 Mammmail_WP8

Comment: Rename Your MainPage like MainPage1 that is I am using.

Comment: It should work now for you . Let me knwo if still you are getting any issue.

Comment: UriMapper does not exist in namespace System.Windows.Navigation;assembly=Microsoft.Phon‌​e. :/

Comment: Add reference to System.Windows.Navigation

Answer (score 0):

In App.xaml.cs page check the following,

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
        {

            if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("Parse.CurrentUser"))
            {
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/email.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
        }
```

Comment: you cant call NavigationService without instantiating an object like `this.NavigationService.Navigate()`. :(

Comment: you cant call NavigationService without instantiating an object like this.NavigationService.Navigate(). :(

Comment: navigationService.Navigate() will make the new instance of page everytime?